# Cannot get Data into PHP webservice from JSON in Android

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONObject;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            final String value = editText.getText().toString();

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                        jsonobj.put("name", value);

                        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("http://www.myurl.com/WebserviceInsert2.php");

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

                        Log.d("jsonobj is :>", String.valueOf(jsonobj));

                        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

                        httppostreq.setEntity(se);

                        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

                        String responseText = null;
                        try {
                            responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());   // {"code":1}
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("Parse Exception", e + "");
                        }

                        Log.d("Response Text is : ", responseText);

                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseText);

                        int code = json.getInt("code");

                        if (code == 1)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Error :>", String.valueOf(e));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }



PHP Code:
<?php

    include("include/config.php"); 

    $name=$_POST["name"];
    //echo $name;

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('".$name."')")) 
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));

    $obj->close();

?>
```

Database table field "name" is blank. The Insert Query fire successfully but.. data was not inserting into table.

I think PHP file was not getting properly 'name' argument from POST method which send by android applicaiton(JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not posted actual logcat but you can try this code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
//Get COding
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(your_url);
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", value));
//you can add  more parameters here
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

you can add or set content type or Header Usual read this for more
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 0):

Because your requesting that url using GET, Method. If your sending any request to the server without mentioning then HttpClient will assume that request for GET, But in your PHP your mentioned its $_POST["name"]; If you replace =$_POST["name"]; with _REQUEST["name"];

Or else you have to set the request type is Post.

Then data may going to inserted to database.